# trying to filter out results with checkboxs

Tags: javascript, filter, jsfiddle

So I have these divs that are essentially results, I am trying to filter through said results using checkboxes and data-category tags.

Here is the code I am using below it works except for it should only show the divs if its data category tags match all checkboxes selected. But in this script if you select boditrak, trackman, and indoor it will show each result that has any of those not just the ones that contain each tag

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anthonyw17/1thaf8vq/)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>


    <input type='checkbox' name="sq-filter" value="trackman" id="trackman">trackman<br>
    <input type='checkbox' name="sq-filter" value="boditrak" id="boditrak"> boditrak<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="sq-filter" value="kvest" id="kvest">kvest<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="sq-filter" value="slowmotion" id="slowmotion">slowmotion<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="sq-filter" value="indoor" id="indoor">indoor<br>

<p>
    <div class="filters">

        <div data-id="golfer" data-category="boditrak trackman slowmotion">
            <p>Golfer Name - boditrak trackman slowmotion</p>
        </div>

        <div data-id="golfer" data-category="indoor slowmotion trackman">
            <p>Golfer Name - indoor slowmotion trackman</p>
        </div>

        <div data-id="golfer" data-category="kvest boditrak trackman">
            <p>Golfer Name - kvest boditrak trackman</p>
        </div>

        <div data-id="golfer" data-category="indoor slowmotion">
            <p>Golfer Name - indoor slowmotion</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
var byProperty = [];

        $("input[name=sq-filter]").on( "change", function() {
            if (this.checked) byProperty.push("[data-category~='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']");
            else removeA(byProperty, "[data-category~='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']");
        });


        $("input").on( "change", function() {
            var str = "Include items \n";
            var selector = '', cselector = '', nselector = '';

            var $lis = $('.filters > div'),
                $checked = $('input:checked');  

            if ($checked.length) {  

                if (byProperty.length) {        
                    if (str == "Include items \n") {
                        str += "    " + "with (" +  byProperty.join(',') + ")\n";               
                        $($('input[name=sq-filter]:checked')).each(function(index, byProperty){
                            if(selector === '') {
                                selector += "[data-category~='" + byProperty.id + "']";                     
                            } else {
                                selector += ",[data-category~='" + byProperty.id + "']";    
                            }                
                        });                 
                    } else {
                        str += "    AND " + "with (" +  byProperty.join(' OR ') + ")\n";                
                        $($('input[name=fl-size]:checked')).each(function(index, byProperty){
                            selector += "[data-category~='" + byProperty.id + "']";
                        });
                    }                           
                }

                $lis.hide(); 
                console.log(selector);
                console.log(cselector);
                console.log(nselector);

                if (cselector === '' && nselector === '') {         
                    $('.filters > div').filter(selector).show();
                } else if (cselector === '') {
                    $('.filters > div').filter(selector).filter(nselector).show();
                } else if (nselector === '') {
                    $('.filters > div').filter(selector).filter(cselector).show();
                } else {
                    $('.filters > div').filter(selector).filter(cselector).filter(nselector).show();
                }

            } else {
                $lis.show();
            }   

            $("#result").html(str); 

        });

        function removeA(arr) {
            var what, a = arguments, L = a.length, ax;
            while (L > 1 && arr.length) {
                what = a[--L];
                while ((ax= arr.indexOf(what)) !== -1) {
                    arr.splice(ax, 1);
                }
            }
            return arr;
        }
</script>   
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with **comma** `,` which you are adding between each `[data-category~=]` in `selector` variable. So jQuery is looking for element which has any one of these `data-category`. So just remove comma, then only jQuery will start looking for those element which have all those `data-category`

Your selector value should be `[data-category~='trackman'][data-category~='boditrak']` instead of `[data-category~='trackman'],[data-category~='boditrak']`

```js
var byProperty = [];

        $("input[name=sq-filter]").on( "change", function() {
            if (this.checked) byProperty.push("[data-category~='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']");
            else removeA(byProperty, "[data-category~='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']");
        });


        $("input").on( "change", function() {
            var str = "Include items \n";
            var selector = '', cselector = '', nselector = '';

            var $lis = $('.filters > div'),
                $checked = $('input:checked');  

            if ($checked.length) {  

                if (byProperty.length) {        
                    if (str == "Include items \n") {
                        str += "    " + "with (" +  byProperty.join(',') + ")\n";               
                        $($('input[name=sq-filter]:checked')).each(function(index, byProperty){

                                selector += "[data-category~='" + byProperty.id + "']";                     
                                        
                        });                 
                    } else {
                        str += "    AND " + "with (" +  byProperty.join(' OR ') + ")\n";                
                        $($('input[name=fl-size]:checked')).each(function(index, byProperty){
                            selector += "[data-category~='" + byProperty.id + "']";
                        });
                    }                           
                }

                $lis.hide(); 
                console.log(selector);
                console.log(cselector);
                console.log(nselector);

                if (cselector === '' && nselector === '') {         
                    $('.filters > div').filter(selector).show();
                } else if (cselector === '') {
                    $('.filters > div').filter(selector).filter(nselector).show();
                } else if (nselector === '') {
                    $('.filters > div').filter(selector).filter(cselector).show();
                } else {
                    $('.filters > div').filter(selector).filter(cselector).filter(nselector).show();
                }

            } else {
                $lis.show();
            }   

            $("#result").html(str); 

        });

        function removeA(arr) {
            var what, a = arguments, L = a.length, ax;
            while (L > 1 && arr.length) {
                what = a[--L];
                while ((ax= arr.indexOf(what)) !== -1) {
                    arr.splice(ax, 1);
                }
            }
            return arr;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' name="sq-filter" value="trackman" id="trackman">trackman<br>
    <input type='checkbox' name="sq-filter" value="boditrak" id="boditrak"> boditrak<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="sq-filter" value="kvest" id="kvest">kvest<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="sq-filter" value="slowmotion" id="slowmotion">slowmotion<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="sq-filter" value="indoor" id="indoor">indoor<br>

<p>
    <div class="filters">

        <div data-id="golfer" data-category="boditrak trackman slowmotion">
            <p>Golfer Name - boditrak trackman slowmotion</p>
        </div>

        <div data-id="golfer" data-category="indoor slowmotion trackman">
            <p>Golfer Name - indoor slowmotion trackman</p>
        </div>

        <div data-id="golfer" data-category="kvest boditrak trackman">
            <p>Golfer Name - kvest boditrak trackman</p>
        </div>

        <div data-id="golfer" data-category="indoor slowmotion">
            <p>Golfer Name - indoor slowmotion</p>
        </div>
  
 </div>
```